# Why is this function not adding one to an int called number?

Tags: c++, function

Why is this code not adding one to the int numbers?

Forgive me for posting a very easy question, I am new to c++.

The value of numbers seem to be unaffected when appearing in the console.
Am I incorrectly passing the function's argument?

```
#include <iostream>
    
    int number = 0;
    int addOne(int a);
    
    int main()
    {
    
        std::cout << "Please type a number to add to one: ";
        std::cin >> number;
        std::cout << number << " plus one equals: ";
        int addOne(number);
        std::cout << number;
       
    }
    
    
    int addOne(int a) {
        
        return a++;
    
    }
```

Comment: You are modifying a variable that only exists inside the function

Comment: The `a` in the function is a copy.

Comment: Also `int addOne(number);` does not call the function, it creates a variable with the same name as the function

Comment: "Am I incorrectly passing the function's argument?" No, you are not passing the function's argument because you are not calling functions.

Comment: What UnholySheep and MikeCAT meant is: `int addOne(number);` indeed looks somewhat like calling a function `addOne(number);`, and somewhat like declaring a function `int addOne(int number);`, but in fact, it's neither. What you wrote (`int addOne(number);`) is... let's say... a special syntax mostly equal to `int addOne = number;`... Yeah, I know, strange. Also, since a few latest versions of C++ standard, you can write the same as `int addOne{ number };`. This madness has a reason, but that's another story. You've got to be extra careful. Or even paranoid. C++ syntax isn't friendly at first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function arguments are **copied** by default, so modifying the copy (in this case `a`) won't affect the original (in this case `number`).

To have functions modify caller's variables, you should use reference.

Also note that `int addOne(number);` in your `main` function is not a function call but a declaration of a variable `addOne` with initializing it to `number`.

```
#include <iostream>

int number = 0;
int addOne(int& a); // add "&"

int main()
{

    std::cout << "Please type a number to add to one: ";
    std::cin >> number;
    std::cout << number << " plus one equals: ";
    addOne(number); // remove "int"
    std::cout << number;
   
}


int addOne(int& a) { // add "&"
    
    return a++;

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the variable by value, which means that the value inside the function will be a copy and the original value will not be modified.

Comment: Appreciate your response!

Answer (score 1):

One more possibility, your function already returns value.
Why not use it?

```
int addOne(int a) { // no &, still passed as copy
    a++;    // increase the copy
    return a;   // return value AFTER increase has been done on 'a'
}

number = 2;
number = addOne(number); // copy in (2), copy out (3)
std::cout << number; // now it's 3
```

Comment: Thank you for providing another method!